# Elmah Does not email in a fire and forget scenario

Tags: elmah

I have a MVC app where I am trying to capture all the incoming requests in a ActionFilter. Here is the logging code. I am trying to log in a fire and forget model.

My issue is if I execute this code synchronously by taking out the Task.Run Elmah does send out an email. But for the code shown below I can see the error getting logged to the InMemory logger in elmah.axd but no emails.

```
public void Log(HttpContextBase context)
        {
             Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException(); //simulating an error condition
                    using (var s = _documentStore.OpenSession())
                    {
                        s.Store(GetDataToLog(context));
                        s.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you're sending an email.  Are you doing that in your `GetDataToLog()` method?  If you are, we're probably going to need to see that code as well.

Comment: I am looking for help on the code in the catch block that using Elmah's Error signalling. The logging happens to a nosql data store.

Comment: You didn't address my question.  Your problem is that an email isn't being sent.  My problem is that there isn't any place in your code that an email is being sent.

Comment: I am using ELMAH for error logging/notifications. Elmah is config driven. The logger are configured in the web.config. In the application code to log to different configured sinks I need to do just this ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex); Does it answer your question?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);` is supposed to send an email?

Comment: Yes Elmah.ErrorSignal will notify all listeners configured in the web.config.

Comment: Is Elmah configured correctly?  The *only* difference is that you're running the *exact same code* in a Task?

Comment: Yes the only difference is I am running it in a Task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this answer from Atif Aziz (ELMAH Lead contributor) on the ELMAH google group:

> When you use `Task.Run`, the `HttpContext` is not transferred to the thread pool thread on which your action will execute. When `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext` is called from within your action, my guess is that it's probably failing with another exception because there is no current context. That exception is lying with the Task. If you're on .NET 4, you're lucky because you'll see the ASP.NET app crash eventually (but possibly much after the fact) when the GC will kick in and collect the Task and its exception will go “unobserved”. If you're on .NET 4.5, the policy has been changed and the exception will simply get lost. Either way, your observation will be that mailing is not working. In fact, logging won't work either unless you use `Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(ex))`, where a null context is allowed. But that call only logs the error but does not do any mailing. ELMAH's modules are connected to the ASP.NET context. If you detach from that context by forking to another thread, then you cannot rely on ELMAH's modules. You can only use `Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(ex))` reliably to log an error.

Comment: HI kolhapuri.. is there any way to deal with this ? i mean to receive error email